# Shell Script Error

Tags: bash

Can any one tell what wrong with this script ?. Because I am getting the error like

```
./timer: line 9: [13: command not found
./timer: line 12: [13: command not found
```

My script look like

```
#!/bin/bash

   while :
     do
    HOUR=$(date +%H)
    MINUTE=$(date +%M)
    SECOND=$(date +%S)

        if [$HOUR == 13] && [$MINUTE == 12] && [$SECOND == 1]
     then ./binary

    elif [$HOUR == 18] && [$MINUTE == 30] && [$SECOND == 1] 
     then ./binary
    fi

    done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put a space between the [ ... ]
Example:

```
if [$HOUR == 13] && [$MINUTE == 12] && [$SECOND == 1]
```

Should become

```
if [ $HOUR == 13 ] && [ $MINUTE == 12 ] && [ $SECOND == 1 ]
```

Comment: `==` isn't POSIX, the correct operator to compare string is `=`. However, we don't wan't to compare strings but integers, so we shall use `-eq` instead. Take a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16560284/1071486) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must use `"${VARIABLE}"` and respect spaces for square brackets

This would give :

```
if [ "${HOUR}" == 13 ] && [ "${HOUR}" == 12 ] && [ "${HOUR}" == 1 ]
```

Hope that helps !

Answer (score 1):

the test operators in bash need to have a space by the opening and closing bracket, try

```
[ $HOUR == 13 ] && [ $MINUTE == 12 ] && [ $SECOND == 1 ]
```

and

```
[ $HOUR == 18 ] && [ $MINUTE == 30 ] && [ $SECOND == 1 ]
```

here is a link that you might find useful
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html

Answer (score 1):

Several things:

- You have to put a space after `[` and before `]`.
- It's a good practice to protect your variables using double quotes.
- You have to use the `-eq` operator to compare numeric values (see [Bash conditional operators](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions)).

Like so:

```
if [ "$HOUR" -eq 13] && [ "$MINUTE" -eq 12 ] && [ "$SECOND" -eq 1 ]

elif [ "$HOUR" -eq 18 ] && [ "$MINUTE" -eq 30 ] && [ "$SECOND" -eq 1 ]
```